# How to implement syncing contacts to server with React Native in the optimised way

Tags: react-native, synchronization, contacts

I have been working around with react-native-contacts in my project to sync local contacts to server. The operations of reading and syncing contacts are costly when there is 1000s of contacts and also effects the JS thread and performance. Also, How to detect the updates in contacts and sync the updated contacts to server, react-native-contacts doesn't have this feature built in. Please help me out on how to pull this off.